# Swift keyPath vs protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols, keypaths

I understand the basic idea of keyPaths but I do not understand its use cases. If you already know the type of the instance, you can access their properties easily. If you don’t, protocol already supports read-only, read-write properties. Can someone explain me what I am missing? Anything that we can’t do with protocols but keyPaths or when keypaths are better than protocols?

Comment: Typical use case is [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If you already know the type of the instance, you can access their properties easily. If you don’t, protocol already supports read-only, read-write properties. Can someone explain me what I am missing?

What you're missing is a sense of what's unknown.

In both your sentences you speak of knowing what the instance's properties are. That's not the problem key paths solve. Key paths have nothing to do with knowing the type; they are not in any kind of opposition to types or protocols. On the contrary, before you can use a key path, you have to know *exactly* what the instance's properties are.

Key paths are for when what is unknown is *which* property to access. They provide a way to pass a property *reference* so that someone else can be told to access *that* property.

For example, here's a Person type:

```
struct Person {
    let firstName : String
    let lastName : String
}
```

And here is a function that sorts an array of Persons by *either* the `firstName` *or* the `lastName`, without knowing *which* one to sort by:

```
func sortArrayOfPersons(_ arr:[Person], by prop: KeyPath<Person, String>) -> [Person] {
    return arr.sorted { $0[keyPath:prop] < $1[keyPath:prop] }
}
```

A key path is how you tell this function *what* property to use as a basis for sorting.